# How can I get the credentials for my assumed role using the AWS SDK for Rust?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rust, amazon-iam, aws-sts, aws-sdk-rust

I am using the AWS SDK for Rust to assume a role for making a request under a new account.

As shown in the Python example from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/example_sts_AssumeRole_section.html), I'm looking for credentials like `aws_access_key_id`, `aws_secret_access_key` and `aws_session_token`,

However, the Rust example looks different, and doesn't seem to surface the underlying credentials.

How can I get the credentials for my assumed role using the AWS SDK for Rust?

Comment: assuming a role usually has some context to it. For example, the role might be attached to an EC2 instance, in which case you should be able to just do whatever you want with that role

Comment: Yes, but if you compare python and rust code, you could see deferences in logic. And my question: how to get new credentials like in python code?

Comment: see the full example here: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/python/example_code/sts/assume_role_mfa.py#L34
if you notice, you'll still need AWS access to create an IAM user, which is then used to initiate the STS client. Same with Rust, you'll need AWS access to explicitly assume role. That's why I asked for the specific use case - you might not need this much code in yours :)

Comment: these are also different use cases - the Rust code is a much simpler function, that just assumes a role given to it. The Python example is much more complicated, and TBH I'm not sure when I'd do what they do there. In practice, I'd probably assume the role given to a Lambda/EC2 instance/ECS task, which usually does not involve anything but spinning up the SDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rust example isn't the best (as it's admittedly in preview) & also has an argument named `role_name` when it really should be [`role_arn`](https://docs.rs/aws-config/latest/aws_config/sts/struct.AssumeRoleProvider.html#method.builder)...

That said, to obtain the access key ID, secret access key & session token - just like the Python example - **use the [`ProvideCredentials`](https://docs.rs/aws-credential-types/0.57.1/aws_credential_types/provider/trait.ProvideCredentials.html) method of the `AssumeRoleProvider`**.

```rust
let provider = aws_config::sts::AssumeRoleProvider::builder(role_arn)
    .session_name(session_name.unwrap())
    .configure(config)
    .build()
    .await;

let credentials = provider.provide_credentials().await.unwrap();

println!("AWS Access Key ID: {}", credentials.access_key_id());
println!("AWS Secret Access Key: {}", credentials.secret_access_key());
println!("AWS Session Token: {}", credentials.session_token().unwrap_or_default());
```

---

Here is a complete yet minimal working Rust CLI app to demonstrate the above:

```rust
// cargo.toml

[package]
name = "aws-sdk-for-rust-assume-role-demo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
aws-config = "0.57.1"
aws-credential-types="0.57.1"
aws-types="0.57.1"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }

// main.rs

use aws_config::SdkConfig;
use aws_credential_types::provider::ProvideCredentials;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let config = aws_config::load_from_env().await;
    let role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/xxx".to_string();
    let session_name = Option::from("xxx".to_string());

    assume_role(&config, role_arn, session_name).await;
}

async fn assume_role(config: &SdkConfig, role_arn: String, session_name: Option<String>) {
    let provider = aws_config::sts::AssumeRoleProvider::builder(role_arn)
        .session_name(session_name.unwrap())
        .configure(config)
        .build()
        .await;

    let credentials = provider.provide_credentials().await.unwrap();
    println!("AWS Access Key ID: {}", credentials.access_key_id());
    println!("AWS Secret Access Key: {}", credentials.secret_access_key());
    println!("AWS Session Token: {}", credentials.session_token().unwrap_or_default());
}
```